# Thoughts on a suggested edit I declined that seems to make assumptions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently denied [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22988034) because it seemed to be assuming what the `array` type was. It is **very** likely from context to be a 1D array as their edit notes, but the definition of the variable isn't provided. I'm now on the fence about this decision.

They're probably right, but the OP made the mistake for a reason, and that may help future people with the same mindset.

Yes, in retrospect I should have skipped it because I wasn't as sure as I should have been. I'm curious though what the opinions are from people who would feel comfortable reviewing this edit.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Even if they were right to remove the word "multidimensional" from the title, that suggested edit was *still* wrong for at least two reasons:

1. It left the title in an ungrammatical state. The article "a" should not be used with a noun that begins with a vowel sound (i.e., "array"). The article would need to be changed to "an".
2. It left the tag [multidimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array) in place, which would be an inappropriate tag if the question does not, in fact, refer to a multidimensional array.

So, putting aside whether or not the question is actually about multidimensional arrays, you should still have rejected the edit.

But yeah…the edit was wrong to assume that it is not a multidimensional array. There is absolutely no evidence of that, because the array's definition is not shown. The syntax `array[i,j]` doesn't have anything to do with multidimensional arrays in C, but that doesn't mean they aren't *trying* to work with a multidimensional array.